# understanding increment and decrement

Tags: java

```
public class increaments {
      public static void main(String args[]){

            int a,b,c,d; 

            a=1; b=2; c=++b; d=a++; c++;        


            System.out.println(""+a);
            System.out.println(""+b);

            System.out.println(""+c);

            System.out.println(""+d);
      }
}
```

Result of program:

```
2
3
4
1
```

Actually I can't understand this program as in this program value of `a` and `b` is assigned `1`&`2` resp. But it show `2`&`3` resp. I don't know why, as I have not incremented it, but it still increased.

Please tell why and these increments and decrements work.

Comment: What is mysterious? `++a` and `a++` both increment `a`.

Comment: I know but both work differently I wanna know why value of a & b changed in this program

Comment: They both changed because they were both incremented: `c=++b; d=a++;`

Comment: That's means where ever we use increment and decrement operator they will work for that varible whether they are in equation (c=++b) Right sir?

Comment: Yes. The increment operators increment the variable and return the new/old value. eg `c = ++b)` is the same as `c = (b = b + 1)`

Comment: Oh thanks you so much sir Actually doing self study from book I hope I will ask more from you again sir